# android:priority value for broadcast receiver to get sms first in my app

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

i want to receive sms in my app, but if there is any other app is receiving sms as well , sms will go to that app and i cant do anything with it .
i want to receive sms first in my app

enter code here`<receiver android:name="pk.wisesolutions.smsmanager.activity.IncomingMessage" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SMS functionality has changed as of KitKat (version 4.4, API Level 19).

> i want to receive sms in my app

This is still possible, if your app has the `RECEIVE_SMS` permission, and has an appropriately configured BroadcastReceiver.

> if there is any other app is receiving sms as well , sms will go to that app and i cant do anything with it .

The concept of a default SMS app was introduced with KitKat. The app chosen as the default SMS app listens for the `SMS_DELIVER` action broadcast, and is responsible for handling the appropriate notifications and Provider writes. Only the default app has control over messages being written to the Provider.

The `SMS_RECEIVED` action is still broadcast, but it cannot be aborted. This means that your app can still listen for and retrieve incoming SMS messages, but it cannot stop other apps from doing so as well, and vice versa. Though the maximum practical priority you can set for your Receiver is `999`, it is rather irrelevant, in this case, because `abortBroadcast()` will not work, and any app listening for the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast will still get it. If your app is not receiving and handling this broadcast, there are other things going on.

Comment: Mike basically i want to block sms , but if i install another app which is also doing the same , then that app is successful in aborting sms and sms didnt reach to my app, so i think my number is second , i want to receive sms first

Comment: Which broadcast action is your receiver listening for?

Comment: android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED this is action

Comment: first , i was using abortBroadcast to abort the sms , but its not working 
says, it will only work with Context.sendOrderedBroadcast 
will you please guide me

Comment: Starting with KitKat, only the default SMS app can "block" messages in any kind of way. Even then, though, normal 3rd-party apps cannot abort the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast. Make sure your app isn't disabling it's BroadcastReceiver when it's not the default.